# Download data from google trends into R with a loop

Tags: r, loops, download, google-trends, gtrendsr

I need to download the search volume from Google Trends for several words. Afterwards I'd like to save the files as csv.

I tried the following:

*words <-c("Tennis","Fußball", "Handball") 
for ( i in 1:length(words) ){
trends <- gtrends(words[i], geo="DE",start_date = as.Date("2004-01-01"), end_date = as.Date(Sys.time()))$trend
write.csv(trends, file="trends.csv")
}*

Obviously the data in trends gets overwritten, so that just the last word in this case Handball remains. How do I download several data?

Thank you for your help!

Ricarda

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
library(gtrendsR)
# Switch https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to on if needed:
gconnect("username", "password")
words <-c("Tennis","Fußball", "Handball") 
trends<- gtrends(words, geo="DE",start_date = as.Date("2004-01-01"), end_date = as.Date(Sys.time()))
for (word in tolower(words)) 
  write.csv( trends$trend[, c("start", "end", word)], paste0(word, ".csv") )
```

Answer (score 0):

do this.

```
write.csv(yourobject$tableframe, file= "filedir\\filename.csv")
```

to get tables do `names(myobject)`

then you nailed it.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.  (and please format your code)